# Finding combinations of binary numbers (matching 1's digits)

Tags: algorithm, binary, combinatorics

Given a binary number, 
What would be the algorithm to find all the matching binary numbers where all the 1's are corresponded to the given number.

For example:
Input: 10010
output: [10010, 10011, 10110, 10111, 11010, 11011, 11110, 11111]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Well, I tried parsing to string and using replace(0,1) but it doesn't give all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use some bit tricks

Let's consider byte size variable with initial value:
`v = 00010010`
Find the next power of two: *(NB: there are more effective methods)*

```
 b = 1
 while (b <= v)
     b = b << 1
```

now `b = 00100000`
make mask `bm = b - 1 = 00011111`
inverted initial value:
`n = not v = 11101101`
clear leading bits:
`mask = n & bm = 00001101`

This `mask` value contains all bits we need to fill. There is bit trick to enumerate all submasks of given bit mask: (and we output union of submask and initial value)

```
sub = mask
while (sub) {
    output sub | v
    sub = (sub - 1) & mask;
   //clears LSB, sets trailing 0s, removes bits not presenting in mask
}
output sub | v
```

Delphi code:

```
var
  v, b, bm, n, mask, sub: Byte;
begin
  v := 16 + 2;
  if v < 2 then 
    Exit;
  b := 1;
  while (b <= v) do
     b := b shl 1;
  bm := b - 1;
  n := not v;
  mask := n and bm;
  sub := mask;
  while (sub > 0) do begin
    Writeln(IntToBin(sub or v, 8)); //binary representation
    sub := (sub - 1) and mask;
  end;
  Writeln(IntToBin(sub or v, 8));
```

outputs:

```
00011111
00011110
00011011
00011010
00010111
00010110
00010011
00010010
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hint of the answer :** You want to keep the 1 where they are. So basically, the recognized language of your system is {0}.

### Solution #1 : The ugly one

Brut-force it and take 2^n binary numbers where n is the size of your number. Keep only those matching your pattern.

### Solution #2 : The simplified one

Again, you want to keep the 1 where they are. So, you want to find all binaries with a pattern, let's call **G** the set of positions of all your 1. Your number is sized **N**, the number of 1 is **i**.

Meaning that, you only have to take all the binaries sized **2^(N-i)-1** in a table of characters table (let's name it **B**) and add a 1 at each position contained in **G**.

#### Example :

Input :  10010
G = {1,4} (0-based, we are on a computer)

Generate a **2^(N-i)-1** table = [000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110, 111]

Put those numbers in B (n is standing for *null*) and replace each *null* with your numbers :
**1st step** : [1nn1n, 1nn1n, 1nn1n, 1nn1n, 1nn1n, 1nn1n, 1nn1n, 1nn1n]
**2nd step** : [10010, 10011, 10110, 11010, 10111, 11010, 11110, 11111]

#### Note :

Remember those solutions are string-based. You could probably not implements those solutions in every language. If you need to bring an algorithm bit-based, just take binaries from 0 to **2^N-1** and perform an **OR** operation with your binary on each. (equals to Solution #1 without regex)